# Divs are not rendering correctly

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, html, rendering

Here is some code from a practice site I'm making. It runs fine, the only thing is that there is no padding between the form and button despite my explicitly stating "padding-top: 50px;". In IE 9 with quirks mode on it renders the padding, but without quirks mode, or using Firefox (14), there is no padding.

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<div id="thumbails" class="thumbnails">
    <?php
        $query="SELECT page_title, page_thumb FROM `pages` WHERE page_thumb != ''";
        if($result = $mysqli->query($query))
        {
            $i = 1;
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {?>
                <div id="container<?php echo $i?>" class="container" style="width:25%; float:left;">
                <img src="<?php echo $row[page_thumb]?>" height=220 width=200 />
                <input class="cbox" type="checkbox" name="pages[]" value="<?php echo $row[page_title]?>"/>
                </div>
            <?php
                $i++;
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
<div id="submit" class="submit"  style="padding-top:50px;text-align:center;">
    <input type="submit"/>
</div>
</form>
```

When I use Firebug to inspect it, it's showing that the div containing the submit covers the whole form not just the submit button. In IE developer mode its the same thing unless quirks mode is on in which case it renders just how I want it to. But I don't see any quirks! What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Please, do not use echo to write HTML code: with all that escape is unreadable and it is easier to make mistake. You can close the php tag, do HTML and then re-open php:
`while(something){?> <em>my HTML</em> <?php}`

Back to the question: are you using also a .css file with #submit, .submit, #thumbnails and .thumbnails?

Comment: No I'm not using any external css yet. I'm more just trying to practice PHP and MySQL, but this padding thing is really irritating me.

Comment: Are you using a stylesheet or are all of your styles applied inline?  The reason I ask is that it would be nice to see ALL styles applied to the elements shown above: thumbnails, form, submit, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that *thumbnails* div has not a specified height. The divs contained into thumbnails are floating, so their heights are not calculated for the final height of the father div. The result is that *thumbnails'* height is 0, so the *submit div* calculate is *padding-top* from the top page; but the image's height is 200px, so input is pushed down.
If you try:

```
<div id="thumbails" class="thumbnails" style="height:300px;">
```

You will see what you want. To find out this problem usually I put some border around the div.

```
<div id="thumbails" class="thumbnails" style="height:300px; border:1px solid red;">
<div id="submit" class="submit"  style="padding-top:50px;text-align:center;border:1px solid green;">
```

So I see margin and padding immediately.